# Issue with DateDiff()

Tags: php, datetime

i found out how to calculate the age of the user by taking in their date of birth in the format of day, month and year in select boxes. Next, i parse their dob in dd-mm-yyyy format. I create a new DateTime and name it as today and then i just use DateDiff in order to find the age. Problem is DateDiff() is no longer supported in newer versions of php. 
Anyone know a work around that i can use with my existing codes? 
Sorry im a newbie, so i might need alot of examples for your suggestions.

Calculate Age

```
$d=$_POST['day'];
$m=$_POST['month'];
$y=$_POST['year'];

//converting Inputed DOB in "dd-mm-yyyy" format
$dob=$d.'-'.$m.'-'.$y;

//Create a new date object with current system date
$bday=new DateTime($dob);

//Differentiating both dates
$age=$bday->date_diff(new DateTime);

$today=date('d-m-Y');


$birthdate = mysql_prep($dob);
$c_age = $age->y;
```

Comment: Who says `date_diff()` is not supported in newer versions of PHP? It's only been available since 5.3: http://www.php.net/date_diff

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$age = $bday->diff(new DateTime);
```

or:

```
$age = date_diff($bday, new DateTime());
```

---

```
$c_age = $age->y;
```

both versions are possible, please refer to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: erm what i got was this error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_diff() in /home/mydentis/public_html/test/create_patient.php on line 45

Comment: which version of php are you using?

Comment: PHP 5.2.17, erm is this considered old?

Comment: Yes, and at least it does not support `date_diff`, what you require. Have you read the manual?

Comment: None of it seem to work from datetime::diff to ->diff, how do i make today's datetime to minus the dob's date time so that i can get the age variable with php 5.2 ? 

I tried the other tutorials on the manual for 5.2 but they did not work either.

Comment: The answer is obvious: upgrade your PHP

Comment: Sorry, i called the operator and it requires service charge and all that. The client is not willing to upgrade. Im sorry but do you know of an alternative method i can use to come up with the same outputs in PHP 5.2 ?